# Does Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount validate claims to mitigate N0Auth?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, openid-connect, identityserver4

When using the Nuget package "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount" (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount/), does this follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/claims-validation to mitigate the N0Auth takeover (https://www.descope.com/blog/post/noauth)?

I can see in "https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/MicrosoftAccount/src/MicrosoftAccountOptions.cs" that the email claim gets mapped to either the "mail" (not sure what this actually is) or the upn (which according to Microsoft recommendations is unreliable).

Would this be enough to prevent N0Auth?